# Facebook API : how to search groups and pages with single request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to search all the groups and pages for a keyword using facebook api

Now i am searching them with two requests

first

```
GET/V2.8/search?q=facebook&type=page&fields=.....
```

second

```
GET/V2.8/search?q=facebook&type=group&fields=.....
```

Is there any method two combine these two requests into one. ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Batch Requests: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

It will still count as 2 separate API calls (for the rate limits), but it will be as fast as the slowest call.

Comment: thanks,  I knew this , but it takes almost same time , as you said it is still two requests, And i think there is no other way , so i wiil mark it as accepted answer